# Optimization of an algorithm performed on a big array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

I have a query that populates an array from the database. In some cases, this query returns a great amount of data, (let's say for purpose of an example, 100.000 records). Each row of the database has at least 6 or 7 columns.

```
$results = [
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name', 'status' => true, 'date' => '10-01-2012'],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name 2', 'status' => false 'date' => '10-01-2013'],
  ...
]
```

I need to perform a substitution of some of the data inside the `$results` array, based on another one that give me some information about how i would change the values in the rows.

```
$model = [
    'status' => ['function' => 'formatStatus', params => ['status']],
    'date' => ['function' => 'formatDate', params => ['date']]
]
```

Now that i have all the data and what do i do with it i have the following routine.

```
foreach ($results as &$itemResult) {
    $oldValues = $itemResult;
    foreach ($itemResult as $attribute => &$value) {
        if (isset($model[$attribute]['function'])) {
            $function = $model[$attribute]['function'];
            $params = $model[$attribute]['params'];
            $paramsSize = count($params);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $paramsSize; $i++) {
                $newParams[] = $oldValues[$params[$i]];
            }
            $itemResult[$attribute] = call_user_func_array([$this, $function], $newParams);
            $newParams = null;
        }
    }
}
```

So, for each attribute for each row of my data array, i run check for the existence of a `function` and `params` information. When the attribute in question needs to be replaced, i call the function via `call_user_func_array` and replace the value with the function return value.
Also notice that i am replacing the current array, not creating another, by passing the reference `&$itemResult` inside the loop, so in the end, i have the same array from the beginning but with all columns that needed to be replaced with its new values.

The thing is, for little arrays, this method is quite good. But for big ones, it becomes a pain.

Could you guys provide me some alternative to the problem?
Should i use another data structure instead of the PHP array?

Comment: consuming a lot of ram doesn't make things slow, usually.  rummaging around in that ram inefficiently is what makes things slow...

Comment: I wonder if `iterator_apply` from SPL would be faster?

Comment: @HalfCrazed Hmm, i'll try an implementation with `iterator_apply` and see how it goes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Another possible optimization would be to use SplFixedArray instead of a vanilla array... it's more space and processor friendly with the stipulation that you have to defined the number of elements up front (easily retrieved from your query statement)

Comment: You could change the inner foreach loop to $model (instead of $itemResult) to reduce the loops to the half (with your example data).

Comment: Maybe you could build a "global" replacement array (for values like true and false in formatStatus) to reduce the call_user_func_array calls.

Comment: Did you analyze what takes the most execution time? What if you minimize operations inside your functions called by call_user_func_array to fe. concatenate old value with any constant string? If the most execution time comes from this function and values are repeating you could use cache.

Comment: @hellcode Your first suggestion is a good one. There are cases with more total columns than columns to be replaced, so iterating over them is a great idea.

Comment: @Skamielina I'll take a look at caching functions, thx for the suggestion.